# CakePHP database queries DISTINCT / GROUP BY error

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

In my CakePHP model I'm trying to get some data from my table.
I tried using DISTINCT but it seems like using DISTINCT doesn't change the query results.
I can see many rows that has the same **nick**

with **'DISTINCT Mytable.nick'**

```
$this->Mytable->find('all',
    array(
        'fields'=> array(
            'DISTINCT Mytable.nick',
            'Mytable.age', 'Mytable.location',
        ),
        'conditions' => array('Mytable.id >=' => 1, 'Mytable.id <=' => 100),
        'order' => array('Mytable.id DESC')
));
```

with **'group Mytable.nick'**

```
$this->Mytable->find('all',
    array(
        'fields'=> array(
            'Mytable.nick',
            'Mytable.age', 'Mytable.location',
        ),
        'conditions' => array('Mytable.id >=' => 1, 'Mytable.id <=' => 100),
        'group' => 'Mytable.nick',
        'order' => array('Mytable.id DESC')
));
```

with **'Mytable.nick'**

```
$this->Mytable->find('all',
    array(
    'fields'=> array(
            'Mytable.nick',
            'Mytable.age', 'Mytable.location',
    ),
    'conditions' => array('Mytable.id >=' => 1, 'Mytable.id <=' => 100),
    'order' => array('Mytable.id DESC')
));
```

Edit: It seems like even CakePHP 2.1 can't use DISTINCT option. When I tried "GROUP BY" it solved my issue. But as you can see from my query I need to order results with **Mytable.id** descended. When I use GROUP BY, when Mysql finds relevant row, it doesn't take others. For example.

- id=1, nick=mike, age=38, location=uk
- id=2, nick=albert, age=60, location=usa
- id=3, nick=ash, age=42, location=uk
- id=4, nick=albert, age=60, location=new_zelland

When I use `group Mytable.nick`, I don't see 4th row in my results, I see 2nd row. Because when mysql saw "albert" second time, it doesn't put it into my results. But I need latest "albert" result. Is it not possible?

Edit2: It seems like order by/group by conflict is a common problem. I found some tips in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924494/mysql-group-by-ordering). But it gives solution for native Mysql queries. I need a solution for CakePHP type queries.

Comment: Think this is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718482/using-distinct-in-a-cakephp-find-function

Comment: Thank you. I edited question with following error.

Comment: Sounds like you need to GROUP BY each field returned to prevent the grouping on 'nick' alone.

Comment: @ficuscr I'm sorry I didn't understand..

Comment: I think the link you provide shows the added complexity when returning a limited offset used with order/group by.  I do not think you face the same obstacle.  What you are trying to do should certainly be possible even with Cake.  That said when I had to use that "framework" ended up with more that a few `$db->rawQuery()`.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear on why you want to group by nick and order by id.  Do you intend to use an aggregate function like `COUNT()` to see how many occurrences of the same nick there are?  In short you overall goal still is not clear to me.  Might be worth being aware of the `HAVING` MySQL keyword.

Updated: Ok, that makes more sense.  So you need to use a sub select on the condition or perhaps express that as a join.  I'll try and show an example using the sub select in the WHERE clause.

```
/* select last occurrence for each nick (if you need one for each location )*/
SELECT nick, age, location
FROM myTable t1
WHERE id =
    (SELECT MAX(id) 
    FROM myTable t1
    WHERE t1.nick = t2.nick);
```

Would think something like this would work:

```
$this->Mytable->find('all',
    array(
    'fields'=> array(
            'Mytable.nick',
            'Mytable.age', 'Mytable.location',
    ),
    'conditions' => array('Mytable.id =' => '(SELECT MAX(id) FROM myTable t2 WHERE myTable.nick = t2.nick)', 'Mytable.id <=' => 100)
));
```

Comment: changing my group line to **'group' => array('Mytable.nick', 'Mytable.age', 'Mytable.location')** and **removing group line** gives same results.

Comment: this is a login table. I record each login of user to this table. Sometimes I need to query users. I want to know latest locations, ages, etc. of user. Users can have different loactions in each login. So I need latest record of each user.