# cakephp distinct find error

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, distinct

I am using cakephp2.7 and need to get distinct values from a table

```
$rows = $this->Skill->find('list',array(
            'conditions'=>array(
                    'Skill.status'=>1,
                    'Skill.percent >='=> 70,
                    'Skill.percent <='=> 100,
                ),
            'fields' => array('DISTINCT Skill.row AS row'),
            //'fields' => 'DISTINCT Skill.row AS row',/*also tried*/
        ));
```

but it is giving mysql error `...near DISTINCT....`
generated query is as below

```
SELECT `Skill`.`id`, DISTINCT `Skill`.`row` AS `row` FROM `mydb`.`skills` AS `Skill` WHERE `Skill`.`status` = 1 AND `Skill`.`percent` >= 70 AND `Skill`.`percent` <= 100
```

i tried same query in mysql giving same error but when I remove `id` column in mysql query it is running fine.

now issue is that `skill.id` column is added in query automatically by cakephp and it is `primary key`
how to prevent including `id` column in `find()`?

Comment: Have you tried GROUP BY skill.row instead of using select distinct? It should give you the same result without the issue of DISTINCT.

Comment: I have added `'group'=>array('Skill.row'),` and removed distinct keyword but it wrong result

Comment: Can you update your question with the new query and the array you get? Ps. I am not so familiar with cake php but you should get a query that in the end has group by skill.row without involving any array

Comment: You need to describe the output you want (e.g., the format of  `find`'s returned array.) Why are you using the `'list'` option that `find`? I would suggest you simply change the `'list'` to `'all'` in the `find`.

Comment: yes @Agrizzo replacing `list` with `all` worked but values are too nested, I want to have as `list`

Comment: I don't know what "too nested" means. You need to show the working code, how the result is formatted AND what you want the result to look like (within your question above.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using DISTINCT in a CakePHP find function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718482/using-distinct-in-a-cakephp-find-function)